# how can i get date of every 7th day from start date for a period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

how can i get date of every 7th day from start date for a period of time.

I have a scheduler that is supposed to run at every 7 days after its start datetime is set to send push notification for every time zone.

eg.

```
   start_time              run_every          end_time
20-july-2016 10:00:00      7_days       25-dec-2016 10:00:00
```

then i will run scheduler every 7 days from `20-july-2016 at 10 am. that will be 28-july, 4-aug, 11-aug and so on.`

The problem is its supposed to be run for all time zones so that user in australia can get notification on 20-july-2016 10:00:00 and user in US should also get notification on  20-july-2016 10:00:00.

for that I am running scheduler on `start_date, start_date+1.days, start_date-1.days` because my server is in UTC timezone so that it can occupy 10 am of every timezone.

I cant figure out a way to run it in intervals of 7 days. how can i get next running dates and check every day that should i run this notification today?

Comment: Try thinking in seconds, not days.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512904/how-to-create-an-infinite-enumerable-of-times

Answer (score 4):

To get the list of running dates in UTC you could use this:

```
(1.month.ago.utc.to_i..1.week.from_now.utc.to_i).
  step(7.days).
  map { |v| Time.at(v).utc }

# => [2016-06-18 17:27:18 UTC, 2016-06-25 17:27:18 UTC, 2016-07-02 17:27:18 UTC, 2016-07-09 17:27:18 UTC, 2016-07-16 17:27:18 UTC, 2016-07-23 17:27:18 UTC]
```

From this point you should be able to perform any timezone adjustments you like. Note that `Range` has timezone-aware methods such as [step_with_time_with_zone](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Range/step_with_time_with_zone).

Also you might want to consider using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for cron scheduling (if you use that) or [ice_cube gem](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) for recurrence calculation.

Comment: _"Note that Range has timezone-aware methods such as step_time_with_zone"_ - can you post the link for the reference?

Comment: Sorry, messed up the method's name. Fixed and added a link.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar task and I used [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) gem, which makes *"recurring events"* easier to handle.

[Daily example](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube#daily):

```
# every third day
schedule = Schedule.new(Time.now)
schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.daily(3)

# Occurrences until a time
schedule.occurrences Time.tomorrow
```